# Find and replace in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string in excel 1_6_2014__12-20-00_AM in excel, is it possible to use a function where to rpelace first two "*" with "/" and the next two "*" with space and the last "_" with space as well.

may be find and replace functions to be used together?

Comment: You can use nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions.

Comment: thanks for reply @RonRosenfeld, can you explain with a simple example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","/",1),"_","/",1),"_"," ")
```

[image]

This takes advantage of the fact that `SUBSTITUTE()` can replace either a **specific** instance of a string or **all** instances of a string.